# Deduce the Cup product structure $RP^n$ with $Z$ coefficient from $Z_2 $ coefficient

Tags: algebraic-topology

while I read Hatchers Algebraic topology book (pg:214) he says that " we can deduce the cup product structure of $RP^n$ with $Z$ coefficient from the cup product structure with $Z_2$ coefficient ? " Is it clear I couldn't seen it yet ?

Thanks for help!

Comment: I cannot find this statement on page 214?

Comment: Sorry for being late. But later I understand What Hatcher says at page 222 in http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf. ıt is just algebra using the projection Z-->Z^2